AWS SQS error : The security token included in the request is expired

AWS sqs config class for aws sqs connection

@Configuration
@EnableSqs
public class AwsSqsConfig {

    @Bean
    public SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory simpleMessageListenerContainerAddAndPlanListQueue(AmazonSQSAsync amazonSQSAsync) {
        SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory simpleMessageListenerContainer = new SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory();
        simpleMessageListenerContainer.setAmazonSqs(amazonSQSAsync);
        simpleMessageListenerContainer.setAutoStartup(true);
        simpleMessageListenerContainer.setMaxNumberOfMessages(15);
        simpleMessageListenerContainer.setWaitTimeOut(1);
        simpleMessageListenerContainer.setBackOffTime(Long.valueOf(20000));
        return simpleMessageListenerContainer;
    }
}


As our service has IAM role access, so create default credentials to run application locally

@Configuration
public class AWSConfig {

    @Bean
    public AwsCredentialsProvider awsCredentialsProvider() {
        return DefaultCredentialsProvider.create();
    }

}


getting below error from configuration class

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'simpleMessageListenerContainer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/aws/messaging/config/annotation/SqsConfiguration.class]: The security token included in the request is expired (Service: AmazonSQS; Status Code: 403; Error Code: ExpiredToken; Request ID: 0b2aff94-b7d4-5ec2-bb37-a053044e8c2f; Proxy: null)


This application is not running locally. Could you please suggest what needs to be done to run the app locally? It is working fine in the AWS environment (DEV)


How are you supplying AWS credentials when running locally?

I suppose default credentials should work and auto detect.
